# Download Wamp onto a Shared Drive so everyone in school can access HTML and PHP pages

Tags: php, wamp, lan, intranet

I am new to all things servers but I am competent enough to understand. Please point me in the right direction.

At school, we have a 'shared drive'. I downloaded, set-up, and ran a WAMP server. I created HTML pages with PHP code to send/retrieve data from the database. I didn't want it on the internet, only locally accessible.

I then decided to move this to the 'shared drive' so that everyone on the school network could access it by simply going to their favorite browser on a school computer and typing 'localhost:8080/' like I do on mine.

I copied and pasted everything, the entire 'Wamp64' folder with all my changes included, onto a folder in the shared drive. I modified the 'http-vhost.conf' file

DocumentRoot "I:/Laboratory/Internal/Server/wamp64/www/project1/"
  Directory "I:/Laboratory/Internal/Server/wamp64/www/project1/"

as follows with the new path. Still, nothing when I got onto a PC and typed 'localhost:8080/'

This is all I've done. Every single step.

I understand how naive my understanding may seem. Please, point me in the right direction.

Comment: are you running WAMP on the server itself?

Comment: I copied and pasted the Wamp64 on shared drive and then I go to the Application file, click on it, and run it that way. I realize that I may not really understand your question. Again, sorry for the newbie-ness.

Comment: You are still running the site on your local workstation then.  What you are trying to do is not possible unless you have access to the server itself.  And the chances are the system administrators are not going to allow you to do what you want to do.  In addition to this there are several steps you need to take to make the server accesiable to the local network as by default its only available to your `localhost`, which brings up another point when you do this you will need to access the site by the computer/server name or its internal IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point of what a web server is i.e. Apache.

It is a software server and as such can sit on any PC in your network, which could be the server or the little old box in the corner that no one ever uses because it is a bit out of date.

It sits on that PC and listens for things trying to connect to it, usually on port 80, but could be any port like your 8080.

So, placing it on the hardware server itself is not necessary.

And, just copying an install to a shared drive and expecting an PC on the network to be able to then us it is just not possible.

Also, its always best to **install** WAMPServer i.e. Apache, where you want it to be located. Copying an installed version from one drive to another never works, as the install modifies path data all over the place and of course the Apache and MySQL services are installed (windows service installed) from the original drive and folder. So your moving the `wamp` folder to another machine will definitely not work.

I suggest you install a WAMPServer on a PC that is left on all the time, using port 80,  I am guessing that the school wont let you install it on their server for obvious reasons.

Then copy your site code to this new installation.

Then backup you database, and restore it to the new machines WAMPServer (MySQL)

Then amend the Apache config to allow access from the schools local network but not the internet, by amending the `httpd.conf` or if you are using WAMPServer 3 by amending the `httpd-vhost.conf` file, there are many answer available on that subject.

Next, if the school has a DNS Server, I would ask for a domain name to be added to that, pointing to the ip address of the PC you installed WAMPServer on. The domain can be anything but something like `davidproject.school` could be used.

Then you create a Virtual Host in WAMPServer using the `ServerName = davidproject.school` and `ServerAlias = www.davidproject.school`

Then people will access it from any browser in the school with the url `davidproject.school`

Comment: Thank You very much for this explanation. It really does help me.